# SQL: Tracking changes to the table that gets truncated everyday (and repulled form different srvr)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a table that is a replicate of a table from a different server.

Unfortunately I don't have access to the transaction information, and all I have is the table that shows "as is" information & I have a SSIS to replicate the table on my server every day (the table gets truncated, and new information is pulled every night).

Everything has been fine and good, but I want to start tracking what has changed. i.e. I want to know if a new row has been inserted or a value of a column has changed.

Is this something that could be done easily?

I would appreciate any help..

The SQL version is SQL Server 2012 SP1 | Enterprise

Comment: What is SQL server version?

Comment: it's SQL Server 2012 SP1 | Enterprise

Comment: How about SELECT MIN(ID_COLUMN) and you could even select it into a work table that you can come back to?  - UPDATED to MIN as your system pulls off the oldest records and not the newest.

Comment: Not sure how that helps knowing what was modified from the table?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for a perticular table then you can go for a scd(slowly changing dimension) transform in SSIS control flow which will keep the hystory records in different table

or

you can create CDC(changing data capture) method on that table.CDC will help you on monitering of every DML operation in that table.It will inserted in the modified row in the system table.